# Blank rectangle after window resize on mobile screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, fixed

I have a container with `postion:fixed` that takes the whole size of the screen:

```
.layer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

The problem is when you scroll down the page on mobile devices (iPhone and Android) as its address line "shrinks" (i.e. its window height value increases) the `.layer` height remaines the same causing a blank rectangle right under it untill you scroll further.

I've tried to bind a window.resize event to recalculate the `.layer`height on the go:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.layer').css("height", "100%");
});
```

But it had no affect. Any idea?

Comment: Came up with increasing its height to 120%. Would be glad if somebody can point me to a more elegant solution.

Comment: I would use `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;`. Even though setting `height: 100%; width: 100%` *should* do the same, setting all sides sometimes fixes unusual issues.

Comment: can u please post the URL of the page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.layer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

Flex instead of position: fixed:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.layer {
   flex: 1 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Just came up with this, yet no affect.

Comment: Does the parent container have position: relative?

Comment: Yes, its body with position relative.

Comment: You can always use display: flex instead of position: fixed, which is more efficient in mobiles anyway. I will update my answer with this.